# Connection pool for ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, connection-pooling

Usually, in a connection pool for a DBMS, it is acceptable and sometime preferable to have even several hundreds connections.

Looking examples online, I always see connection pools with just a few connections and a large number for the sessions associated to a connection.

Is this because the connections to ActiveMQ are somehow expensive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both database and JMS connections are generally considered "expensive" and should usually be pooled.

In a pooled use-case the number of connections in the pool is really defined by your performance requirements, hardware capacity, etc. It's usually refined via benchmarking and tuning. There are almost always trade-offs between performance and resource utilization so it's your job to find the right balance. Even general recommendations are hard to make for pool size because the use-cases can vary so widely.

In a non-pooled use-case it's worth noting that a single JMS connection can service multiple sessions concurrently (although the sessions themselves can't be used concurrently). JMS sessions are much less expensive to create than JMS connections. Therefore, in a non-pooled use-case it generally makes sense to reduce the number of JMS connections to be as low as reasonably possible and make use of multiple sessions.

Aside from a few bits of setup for the connection all substantive JMS client work is done through the session. JDBC connections have no such "session" idea. Most of the work is done directly on the connection object. Therefore, I'm not sure the comparison here is really valid.

Comment: I am probably missing something. 
I need a session to send a message and I need a connection to start the session. When my method is called to send a message, because I do not want to store the connection, I am always getting it from the pool. This means that every time the method is called I get the connection from the pool and then I create the session. How can the pool create multiple sessions in this case?

Comment: The first thing to note is that the connection only needs to be started if you are *consuming* messages. If you are just sending messages then you don't need to invoke `start()` on the connection. JMS sessions are much less expensive than connections so it shouldn't be a problem to get the connection from the pool and create a session every time. Have you conclusively identified JMS session creation as a bottleneck in your application?

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify the general recommendation for the pooled vs. non-pooled use-cases.

Comment: Just to be sure that I understand your answer, if I am in a pooled use case, the number of connections in the pool can and should be enough to ensure that it does not happen to often that the connections are all taken and the client has to wait. In my use case, where there could be tens of concurrent messages sent, I should configure the connection pool with, for example 30-50 connections. Is this acceptable? Or it's too many?

Comment: Good to know that I do not need to start and stop the connection to send messages.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment about pool size.